# Displacement on certain objects not working

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

In Blender 2.71 using the Cycles engine, I cannot get displacement to work properly on certain objects.

Here are some screenshots of thre three objects and the nodes I'm using for them: water, a cube, and a plane. Although the displacement works fine for the cube and the plane, it refuses to work on the water. The nodes I'm using are based off of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/783/599).

Water nodes:

[image: Water nodes]

Cube nodes:

[image: Cube nodes]

Plane nodes:

[image: Plane nodes]

Viewport:

[image: Screenshot of the scene]

Render:

[image: Render of the scene]

Here's the [.blend](http://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzl8ZZsYnq_XUFJCNGd5N3JTeGc/). You'll also need the texture files from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeZml.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dn1I.png).

Comment: Would you upload the .blend? It'd help us help you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working, it's just that the scale is different due the the water object being so much larger. The texture is so large that it's hard to see the displacement effect. If you plug it into an emission shader after muting the multiply node (<kbd>M</kbd>), then you can see the texture clearly:

[image]

To fix it, either scale up the textures or use a different mapping via the *Texture coordinate* node:

[image]

## Result:

[image]

Comment: @JMY1000 Sorry about the cut-off screenshots, I've fixed it now..