# Displacement Map Not Working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, modifiers

I've got a Minecraft cube that I'm trying to apply a displacement map to, but the displacement is just not working.

So each Minecraft texture is 16x16 pixels, so by taking a cube and subdividing (simple) 15 times, I'll get a 16x16 grid of faces and the displacement map should work, but it's giving me weird geometry.

[image: model with displacment]

Changing the Midlevel doesn't fix it, just gives different types of broken. Scaling it up in edit mode actually helps it, but even after doing that I could see that the texture was not applying. There were bulges in the wrong places.

Here's my settings:
[image: texture settings]

I changed my extension to clip, but switching between the different types doesn't do anything. I had to disable Interpolation because the texture is so small, otherwise it's all blurry. Stuck and not sure what to do.

And disclaimer, I have already read ([Displacement on certain objects not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15277/displacement-on-certain-objects-not-working)) and it doesn't help me. If you read it, you'll see that it's node-based, Voronoi texture. I don't have any nodes since this uses a modifier. It doesn't help me nor solve my problem.

Comment: What exactly are you going after? It's a bit hard to tell.

Comment: Try to change Texture Coordinate in Displace Modifier to UV

Comment: @Denis I'm pretty sure that's the problem.  Could you add that in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what I tried the displacement map wouldn't work. I eventually realized that I had to take a different avenue to get the result I wanted.

I had to manually extrude the faces outward to get the desired result. Took a while, but looks a lot better than any displacement map would have worked. Just go into material or texture mode (to make seeing what you're doing easier) and grab the faces that need to be extruded, and extrude them out the desired amount.

Just thought I'd leave my answer here in case anyone else wanted to know what I did.

Answer (score 4):

To use image as displacement factor in Displace Modifier, Texture Coordinates have to be set to UV and the mesh properly unwrapped.

[image]

Comment: I would modify that answer to state that setting the texture coordinates to UV and unwrapping the mesh is the right choice for the OP in this scenario. The other options are still valid choices for applying the image texture in other scenarios.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh I think that, except in some very specific situations, to use an *image* texture (not procedural) you really have to unwrap the model.

Comment: Not true, you can use other types of texture coordinates (object, local etc) with an image texture. UV is most appropriate in this case due to the precision required with the texture arrangement on the mesh