# How can I make a realistic water material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I have read a lot of posts about water in this forum but none of them seem to be what I am looking for, except this one:

[How can I create a water material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64/how-can-i-create-a-water-material-in-cycles]):[image]

Every time I try to re-make it though it looks all black.

I have tried a load of different material:

[image]
[image]

I have come up with, etc. The first picture below is what I am trying to make (if I could get that water to be correct, then I could tweak it and add the green/blue color like in the image above. [image]

Comment: If it's "all black" as you mentioned, there are probably more serious problems in the scene other than tweking the materials parameters. BTW, it would be helpful if you could explain what exactly you are not satisfied with. What effects are you missing: the ripple? the caustics? the volumetric absorption? why don't it look "realistic" in your opinion? I would say that the glass shader could imitate a cup of still water in a very convincing way: it's the "ensamble" of the scene that matters.

Comment: It is more useful if instead of showing the results only, you show the node tree used as well. I'd hate to suggest something you have tried already,

Comment: I don't actually know that technical term for what I don't like about it. I basically want it to look like real water, have transparency so you can see the things below it, and is have a good ripple (which I do know how to do though). I added the image at the bottom of the original post to show what I want the water to basically look like.